# Converting an NSString to an NSInteger

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, nsstring

if i have:

```
NSString* number = @"2000";
```

Will `NSInteger integerNumber = [number integerValue];`

be equal to the integer representation of 2000?

Comment: Did you try it?  It would've taken less time to write `NSLog(@"%ld", [@"2000" integerValue]);` than it did to write the question...

Comment: Easy questions have value on SO, if only to other noobs down the line. Not that I'm calling you a noob Sheehan. It's just that experienced programmers often forget the million tiny facts they've internalized. They forget that they weren't born knowing those facts.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why not consult [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/integerValue)?

> **integerValue**
>
> Returns the `NSInteger` value of the receiver’s text.
>
> ```
> - (NSInteger)integerValue
> ```
>
> Return Value
>
> The `NSInteger` value of
>   the receiver’s text, assuming a
>   decimal representation and skipping
>   whitespace at the beginning of the
>   string. Returns `0` if the receiver
>   doesn’t begin with a valid decimal
>   text representation of a number.

Comment: Stack Overflow IS the documentation. Dynamically updated with sample code and human-readable explanations. Pretty cool, actually.

Comment: So true. I just realized this is the second time I've viewed this answer and read your comment.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it will be.